# Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null

Tags: javascript, xml, nodes

I have XML:

```
<street></street>
```

or

```
<street>2813 Bla ave</street>
```

Javascript:

```
if ((xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('street')[i].firstChild.nodeValue != null)) {
                 alert(1);
                 }
                 alert(2);
```

But the script doesn't work - Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null

Comment: You should give more details, like the full XML and the full code!

Comment: `.firstChild` is null, so - `xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('street')[i]` has no children.

Comment: @Kolink I'm assuming his javascript resides in some sort of loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nodeValue` will never be `null` because without a value the node wouldn't exist.

Remove `.nodeValue` from your code.

Comment: +1 from me, your answer was helpful, too bad OP never accepted it. I would also suggest making the verification !== null, instead of simply != null

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is failing,

```
 xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('street')[i].firstChild
```

appears to return null. Have you tried logging and checking to make sure that the selector you want actually exists?

Answer (score 0):

The street node does not have any children.  You need to remove `.firstChild`

Answer (score 0):

Use xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('street')[i].innerHTML because the text you want is between the tags. I believe this IS supported for XML. Of course, you could always use the nodeValue property as well.